# Response Headers in AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, jira, put, jira-rest-api

I am using PUT method in ajax to update existing issue in JIRA. To access issue using PUT method we have to add **Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to headers in ajax. I have tried many ways but cannot get these in Response Headers. How, to code in ajax to get a response like this, as shown below,[image]

Comment: isn't this a server-side issue?

Comment: I don't know whether it is a server side issue. I have no idea on how to access it. Can you please help me to overcome this.